# iPod Nano (6th Generation) Lyrics Support

Tags: ipod, ipod-nano, lyrics

I'm thinking of getting an iPod Nano (6th Generation) and I'm not sure if it has support for lyrics.

Does anyone know if it does?

Comment: What do you mean by "support" for lyrics"?

Answer (score 2):

It certainly does; I've had one.

Comment: If they're in iTunes, they'll also be on the iPod.